# How Do I Only Record User Input Text Upon User Button Click?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, input

I'm doing this exercise where I am to take a user's input and change the HTML body's background to match the user input. I am only supposed to use JavaScript for this.

With .addEventListener(`input`) I'm only managing to register each individual character, and am only logging each individual input character; how can I make it so that I register an entire string only upon the user clicks a submit button?

Here is my code so far:

```
inputField = document.createElement(`input`);
inputField.type=`text`;
let counterInt = ``
let counter = ``

inputField.addEventListener(`input`, (e)=>{
    counter= e
    counterInt = `${counter}`
    paragraph.style.backgroundColor= `${counter}`
    console.log(counter);
})
```

The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Green Screen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="cc.html">Cookie Clicker</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="mag.html">Magnifying Glass</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="green.html">Green Screen</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="crane.html">Crane Game</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="dice.html">Dice</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home Page</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <section class="index"></section>
    <section class="green"></section>
    <section class="dice"></section>
    <section class="crane"></section>
    <section class="mag"></section>
    <section class="cookie"></section>
    
    <script src="green.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have verified that it's properly linked and all; I've gotten a few other JS tricks to work, such as a button to increase and minimize text size.

Comment: P)lease show the relevant HTML. In your case, you don't want the listener on your input, but rather a "click" listener on your button, which then accesses the user's input text with `inputField.value`.

Comment: Try using the "change" event instead.  That allows the user to finish typing the color name before updating. It would update when they press the enter key or click elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about using a counter and building a string, just use the value of the event's target.

I'm also removing the pound sign and restricting the input to 6 characters. I'm forcing them to use hex and not color names.

```js
inputField = document.createElement(`input`);
inputField.type=`text`;

let paragraph = document.querySelector("#p");

inputField.addEventListener(`input`, (e)=>{
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace("#","").substr(0,6);
})

let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-change-color");

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  paragraph.style.backgroundColor = "#" + inputField.value
});

document.body.appendChild(inputField)
```

```css
#p{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<button class="btn-change-color">Change Color</button>
```